# How can we write in existing file(.txt)in sdcard in android

Tags: android, file-io, android-sdcard

I want to edit a .txt file which is stored on an sd card. In my app I have to write user activity data.

So, whenever a user opens the app and does something, the .txt file should be updated with  new data.

Comment: may i have some example code?

Comment: you need append text on textfile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this:

```
File externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myFile = new File(externalStorageDir , "mysdfile.txt");

if(myFile.exists())
{
   try
   {
       FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
       OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
       myOutWriter.append("test");
       myOutWriter.close();
       fOut.close();
    } catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
else
{
    myFile.createNewFile();
}
```

just set permission like this

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to open a file using `MODE_APPEND` to append a text into existing file.

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("myfile.txt", MODE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Thx for this good information. I used this for "MODE_APPEND":
public static final boolean MODE_APPEND = true;

Answer (score 0):

I find the Apache Commons library very useful in this case.

[FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). You can append a String to a File with [this function](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

try this simple code in java using `RandomAccessFile`

```
    try
    {
      File f = new File("your-file-name.txt");
      long fileLength = f.length();
      RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");
      raf.seek(fileLength);
      raf.writeBytes("this is append text in text file");
      raf.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
   {

   }
```

this code if file is not exist and automatically created and append it!